# Django hosting static files in AWS S3 causing CORS error when trying to access admin font files

Tags: django, amazon-s3, django-rest-framework, django-admin

I setup Django to store all static files on S3 and with the "collectstatic" command, all the admin files where copied and when I visit the admin site the CSS and JS files are sourced from the S3 bucket correctly. For example:

```
https://bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/static/admin/css/base.css
https://bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/static/admin/js/vendor/jquery/jquery.js
```

But when it tries to access the Font files .woff I get the following error:

```
Access to font at 'https://bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/static/admin/fonts/Roboto-Light-webfont.woff' from origin 'http://localhost:8000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

It's weird that it gives me access to all the files except the font files:

[image]

Comment: have configured permissions of CORS?

Answer (score 9):

Configuring the following in S3 Bucket Permissions > CORS fixed the issue.

```json
[
    {
        "AllowedHeaders": [
            "Authorization"
        ],
        "AllowedMethods": [
            "GET"
        ],
        "AllowedOrigins": [
            "*"
        ],
        "ExposeHeaders": [],
        "MaxAgeSeconds": 3000
    },
    {
        "AllowedHeaders": [
            "*"
        ],
        "AllowedMethods": [
            "HEAD",
            "GET",
            "PUT",
            "POST",
            "DELETE"
        ],
        "AllowedOrigins": [
            "*"
        ],
        "ExposeHeaders": [
            "ETag",
            "x-amz-meta-custom-header"
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: You made my day :D I updated django, installed cors, added S3, nothing worked but the correction of Amazon S3 CORS Permission solved it. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I remember i faced this issue before with Google Cloud Storage.

You have to make your bucket allow origin cross to your domain.

Comment: I can try this, but wouldn't it block the download of all the files, not just the font files?

Comment: Im not sure why this is happening but clearly from the error your static url is blocking access to the fonts for some reason. 

Whitelist your domain and should be working just fine.